# Why can't I select the literal 'gold' with Data Explorer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Not sure if *meta* is the right place to post this. While the following query works with [**Data Explorer**](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new):

```
Select 'silver'
```

this one

```
Select 'gold'
```

gives me an

> **Error:** Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''. Incorrect syntax near ''.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Wow, a gold bug!

Comment: @waffles: Actually, this is just broken for any literal that matches \*go\*.  This must be because of the way the GO statement is implemented on the data explorer.

Comment: Just posted this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52847/dataexplorer-bombs-if-you-use-the-go-keyword

Comment: BIG bug on my part, I will try to deploy a fix today

Comment: `status-completed` just fixed this see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52847/data-explorer-bombs-if-you-use-the-go-keyword/52909#52909

Comment: @waffles: Thanks, that should be sufficient. Would you like to add that link as an answer to my question? This would give me something to accept, and you some well-earned reputation for your excellent work on Data Explorer :) Am I supposed to edit my question and add the `status-completed` tag?

Comment: @Peter, Jeff will take care of that, only admins can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is much better handled now, see: [Data Explorer bombs if you use the GO keyword](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52847/data-explorer-bombs-if-you-use-the-go-keyword/52909#52909)