# Commented-out query parameters still generate page input controls

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

[Demonstration query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/s/200/down-voted-accepted-answers)

[image]

The parameter does a straight replace if you type in a value so the query still runs, but it does force you to enter something before it will run.

<sub>Note: I deliberately did not tag this with `[comments]`.</sub>

Comment: This [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52847/data-explorer-bombs-if-you-use-the-go-keyword/52909#52909) shows waffles has had some trouble confirming where comments start and end.

Comment: Does anybody have js regexes to strip comments?

Comment: @waffles: I turned up this with a quick search, maybe you can adapt it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228185/javascript-regex-capture-everything-except-c-style-comments (that does the block-style comments, but the `--` line comments should be easier to parse).

Comment: @waffles I assume you would have found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462843/improving-fixing-a-regex-for-c-style-block-comments/463339#463339) give it was listed as related to Jon's pointer. I would assume that if you included a string match in this regex first, that would skip the quoted comment starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring the need to revert the code that handles this, this should no longer happen. Parameters listed in both single and multi-line comments will be ignored by the query parser, and you won't be hassled by an input box.