# Data Explorer doesn't like GO after CREATE PROCEDURE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

My original [#Temporary tables, indexes and procedures work!](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/5646/5646/temporary-tables-and-indexes-work) no longer works, so I edited it to confirm temporary tables and indexes can still work -- and [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/5646/temporary-tables-and-indexes-work) now doesn't need GO.

The problem with the original query seems to be the handling of `GO` has broken, but not in the same way as [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52847/data-explorer-bombs-if-you-use-the-go-keyword). Similarly the [three other queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=CREATE+PROC) found by searching for `CREATE PROC` all currently fail.

However `CREATE PROC` still needs to be "the first statement in a query batch" which you can see if you edit [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59573/testing-go) query or its revisions, where I have tried a number of things relating to `GO` and `CREATE PROC`, including starting with confirming the [previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52847/data-explorer-bombs-if-you-use-the-go-keyword) issue is not present and including effectively the same query as from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx#BasicSyntax).

Comment: the GO splitting being broken is a regression, will sort it

Comment: @waffles Was able to root it out, but the overall code there might be misguided on my part

Comment: deployed Tim's fix ... let me know how it goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone (we'll call that person "me") was trying to be clever and reduce query white space to increase our chances of hitting the execution cache. This reduction was doing the decidedly unclever thing of stealing the newline after your `GO` in certain cases.

I've now [made sure we put it back](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=4e39e52adadba5298959012db66f9c96d19b0b02) in my copy of Data Explorer, and we'll see if this operation causes any more problems.